# rails plugin for this site will be launching soon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Sometime back in a blog or in podcast I heard about a rails plugin that takes care of everything you need to worry about launching the site. The webpage will capture the email address of people visiting the site before the launch. And , I think, it also integrates with madmimi to send out emails to those people.

I am not able to recall the name of that plugin. Any one remembers it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://github.com/vinsol/Launching-Soon?

> Launching soon is a plugin that helps rails projects to manage a dedicated launching soon page before the actual launch date. The plugin also collects email from potential customers.